# Magento 2.4.2: Disable/hide reviews tab in the product details page

Tags: magento2, product, php, tabs

The tabs in our product details page include a tab called "Reviews".

Where does that come from, and can it be hidden or eliminated?  The Yotpo system that we're using already has the reviews - and this is just a confusing element for buyers.

Hiding it with CSS is something I know, but I'm looking for a setting in Magento admin to disable this specific tab.

Here is the link to a product [page](https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/alfi-brand-5x-led-hardwired-makeup-mirror-2-finishes.html) on the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `default.xml` if you want to remove reviews tab from all pages
**(And if you only want to remove from Product detail page you can create `catalog_product_view.xml` instead of `default.xml`)** in your custom module

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

or

```
 app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Then add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Now flush the cache and your reviews tab on product detail page get hide

Hope it will solve your issue!